# Shortcode breaking ACF flexible sections while loop

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Using Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) Flexible sections for Wordpress, I have various flexible fields that work great. I've used ACF for years and recetnly started using flexible sections.

I've noticed that when i insert a shortcode into a flexible section (WYSWIG editor or similar), it breaks the loop, and none of the following flexible sections appear on the page, or in the inspector/DOM. I think the shortcode is breaking the while loop.

Heres the shortcode I'm currently trying to insert in a page. It works, but the rest of the page sections after are missing.

```
function spotlight_boxes( $atts ){
        $args = array( 'post_type' => 'customer-spotlight', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_status' => 'publish' );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

        $loopTitle = $atts['title'];

        ob_start(); ?>
        <section class="feature-boxes page">
            <h2 class="center std section-title"><?php echo $loopTitle; ?></h2>
            <div class="small-wrap">
                <div class="boxes flex">
                    <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
                        $customer_logo = get_field("customer_logo");
                        ?> 
                        <div class="feature-box">
                            <span class="tag-btn">Spotlight</span>
                            <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" width="100%"/>
                            <div class="feature-info">
                                <img src="<?php echo $customer_logo['sizes']['medium']; ?>" width="100%">
                                <h5 class="std"><?php the_field('overview_title'); ?></h5>
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="learnmore">Learn More</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <?php

        return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode( 'spotlight_boxes', 'spotlight_boxes' );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are producing content by the function that used to be replaced with a shortcode. As documented in [Wordpress Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_shortcode/),  The function called by the shortcode should never produce an output of any kind. Shortcode functions should return the text that is to be used to replace the shortcode. Producing the output directly will lead to unexpected results. This is similar to the way filter functions should behave, in that they should not produce expected side effects from the call since you cannot control when and where they are called from.

For example, if you are creating an HTML that needs to be replaced with the shortcode the example return should be like

```
$html = '<div class="test-field">';
$html .= get_field('test-field');
$html .= '</div>';
return $html;
```

and not like this

```
the_field('test-field');
```